# how to make an animation run on png images in css?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I have created an animation script on a png image that is `animateCloud`, the animation has worked, but the image does not connect, I want to make the picture does not break at all like there is a repeat in the picture please help how to code?

this is my code

```
<img class="img-baby-g-about for-desktop" src="assets/images/img-desktop-about.png" alt="baby g bga-240 about" width="100%">
```

and this is my css

```
    @-webkit-keyframes animateCloud {0% {margin-left: -100px;}100% {margin-left: 100%;}}
    @-moz-keyframes animateCloud {0% {margin-left: -1000px;}100% {margin-left: 100%;}}
    @keyframes animateCloud  {0% {margin-left: -1000px;}100% {margin-left: 100%;}}

    .img-baby-g-about {
    -webkit-animation: animateCloud 10s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: animateCloud 10s linear infinite;
    animation: animateCloud 10s linear infinite;}
```

I mean my animation runs and will clear the page, but what I want is that the image does not empty the page

Comment: Do you mind if I put that image on an image host that allows hotlinking so I can use it in a snippet to show you?

Comment: sure please help

Comment: I don't understand the problem of this.
Your animation works and repeats perfectly.
Do you mean that only the clouds should move and the rest shouldn't.

Comment: I mean, you see my animation, right? the animation runs and will clear the page, but what I want is that the image does not empty the page @ChristianMeyer

Comment: Edited my answer below to include a more responsive solution that does not depend on image dimensions.

Comment: i wish you erase that image on https://i.postimg.cc/T1nt9ZLk/Lv8L0.png thankyou for help me @VenesemeTyras

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this with an `<img>` element, it must be fairly tricky. You will have to use at least two elements, positioning will be tricky and it would be rather difficult to make it be responsive.

I would recommend that you use a background-image for this because background-repeat is perfectly suited to this sort of thing. If you really want to have an actual `<img>` tag for content/seo purposes or something, then I suggest that background-image is still the way to animate it, and just push the real image into nowhere with negative padding hacks.

Here is how to do it with background image:

```css
.img-baby-g-about {
  width: 100%;
  height: 327px;
  animation: animateCloud 10s linear infinite;
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/T1nt9ZLk/Lv8L0.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background position: 0 0;
}
    
@keyframes animateCloud  {0% {background position: 0 0;}100% {background-position: 1280px 0;}}
```

```html
<div class="img-baby-g-about"></div>
```

---

Considerations:

1. I set the height of the element to 327px because that is the height of the image *(the image host resized it)*. We could use `background-size` to change that, or even use percentages to scale the image, but then the animation would have to be adjusted to also use percentages to accommodate and that will be a little tricky due to how background-position is relative to both the image and the container *(see below)*.
2. I set the 100% animation frame to `position: 1280px 0;` because the image is 1280px wide *(image host ressized it)*.
3. Your original image was 2560x654 *(the image host automatically scaled it).* So to to use your image you should change the relevant pixel dimensions above.

> ## Responsive Solution
>
> So to make this more responsive, and less dependent on the image dimensions lets use percentages to scale and animate the background image, this way you won't need to change it suit different pixel dimensions for different images.
>
> We can't use 100% though, because if we do, background-position becomes useless, because of how background position is relative to both the image and the container, if they are the same, then all points are equivalent, and no shifting can occur. So we'll use 110% for background-size. Then to actually move the image the full width of the image, we will work with the 10% difference between the container and the image, so 110%(the image) x 10(the difference) is 1100%. So that is the amount we shift the background image to move it across it's full width.
>
> I made the container 100% window height and stuck the animation to the bottom of the container. You could adjust that to suit your requirements.
>
> ```css
> html, body {
>   height: 100%;
>   margin: 0;
>   padding: 0;
> }
> .img-baby-g-about {
>   width: 100%;
>   height: 100%;
>   animation: animateCloud 10s linear infinite;
>   background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/T1nt9ZLk/Lv8L0.png);
>   background-repeat: repeat-x;
>   background-position: left bottom;
>   background-size: 110%;
> }
>     
> @keyframes animateCloud  {0% {background-position: 1100% bottom;}100% {background-position: 0% bottom;}}
> ```
>
> ```html
> <div class="img-baby-g-about"></div>
> ```

Comment: thaknyou very much!

Comment: hi @veneseme thankyou a lot but I hope you don't spread the picture thankyou sm

Comment: The same image is here on shutterstock as shown in google [image search](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/surf-bus-sunset-tropical-beach-260nw-1177200334.jpg&imgrefurl=https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/surf-bus-sunset-tropical-beach-retro-1177200334&h=280&w=900&tbnid=kN6UvXeXUY0jeM&tbnh=125&tbnw=403&usg=K_AThtIg83VTH4lLxNbOXP_Xde-mo=&hl=en&docid=7KgSVWkTI021oM&itg=1). I will remove the image if you really think it's important, but you should provide suitable replacement, in order that the answer remains clear for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `background-image` in combination with the `background-position` and `repeat`. When you really want to use the img tag for this I would say you need some JavaScript but you are asking for a css solution here you go:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animateCloud {
0% {background-position: -100% 0; }
100% {background-position: 100% 0;}
}
@-moz-keyframes animateCloud {
0% {background-position: -1000px 0;}
100% {background-position: 100% 0;}
}
@keyframes animateCloud  {
0% {background-position: -1000px 0;}
100% {background-position: 100% 0;}
}

.img-baby-g-about {
background-image: url("https://icon-library.net/images/icon-cloud/icon-cloud-4.jpg");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
-webkit-animation: animateCloud 10s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: animateCloud 10s linear infinite;
animation: animateCloud 10s linear infinite;
}
```

Here is a working Fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/qk1hdeg0/14/

Answer (score 0):

For this, you have to divide your image into multiple images, like Cloud-image, Car and rest of background. Then make CSS animation like this.

```
<code>https://codepen.io/HanumanSahay/pen/QWWPEZz?editors=1100</code>
```